# Passing variable to remote php file for JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, database, titanium

I am building a mobile app using Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.1.201303242433, CLI version 3.0.24, Titanium SDK version 3.0.2.GA, iOS SDK: 6.1, iPad Simulator: 6.1 on MAC OS X10.7.5.
I am attempting to retrieve JSON data from a remote database. The database has records with and without a "sectionid" (sectionids are numbers 1-12). I want to retrieve the records with the "sectionid" I pass to my query. Here are the steps I am following: First I assign a "sectionid" to a tableViewRow like this:

```
leftImage:'images/advertising.png', 
            title:'Advertising',
            sectionid: '1', 
            color:'#000',
            font: {fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:16},
            height:'44dp', 
            hasChild:true, 
            test:'testcatmenu.js'},
```

Then I pass the sectionid to another file like this:

```
var section = e.rowData.sectionid;
win.section = section;
```

In the next file I get the sectionid and pass it to the remote php file like this:

```
var section = Ti.UI.currentWindow.section;
var url = "http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?sectionid='section'";
```

Finally, in the php file I $_GET the sectionid and use it in my MySQL query like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM `cms_client` WHERE sectionid = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['section']) ."'") or die('Could not query');
```

The php file is returning the records that do not have a sectionid, so somewhere I am losing the sectionid? I do not know where my code syntax is wrong, would someone be so kind to show me the correct syntax that I need to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps include `sectionid` in the SELECT? `SELECT name, sectionid FROM \`cms_client\``

Comment: Thanks for posting back, I added but no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the php you are using a variable $_GET['section'] but the GET variable you are passing in is called sectionid (?sectionid=). So either change both to section or both to sectionid.

Also, assuming that the

```
var url = "http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?sectionid='section'";
```

is javascript then it should be something like:

```
var url = "http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?sectionid="+section;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?sectionid='section'";
```

Change that to

```
var url = "http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?sectionid="+section;
```

Javascript allows you to add variables to a string using + variableName

Like

```
var variableT = "foobar";
var strNew = "This string contains the word: "+variableT+" and it works!";
```

Comment: Thanks for posting back, I changed my url and also specifically asked for the sectionid as "SSH This" above recommended, but no change. I opened a browser and tried to force the section id like http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?sectionid=3 and still the file returned just records without a sectionid. An excerpt from the php output is:{"name":"C J McCall Mfr","sectionid":""}. So maybe my problem is in the PHP file?

Comment: $_GET['section'] to $_GET['sectionid'] since you made a GET attribute called sectionid, not section